# Can MvvmCross Messenger Plugin be used across multiple applications?

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross, messaging, portable-class-library

We are getting in the design phase of using MvvmCross for our application platform and we are trying to figure out if we can use the MvvmCross Plugin to broadcast messages between multiple MvvmCross applications? These applications will be running on the same machine in parallel, and on an internal network.

I did consider using RabbitMQ for this but found out that you cannot add RabbitMQ to a Portable Class Library Project. So that's out of the question.

I watched this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQdvrWWzkIk and the speaker says the Messenger can be used within an application, but I would like to know if it can enable communication between different applications.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a Windows Service Hosted, WCF service (NET TCP) which enabled me to do cross process communication. Then when a process received a message via WCF, it relayed the message internally using the MVVMCross Messenger.

Seems to work pretty well so far, although it's only been used with 3 processes. So not sure about the scalability of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it probably creates an instance and uses that for communication, making it less ideal (if possible) for across applications.
You should be able to create a program that listens to a port and redirects accordingly, creating the same functionality though.